# php check if link clicked

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

The question is that how do i check if a link has been clicked?

```
<a href="laggtill.php">+</a>
<a href="laggtill.php">+</a>

(another document)
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['car'] = $_SESSION['car'] + 1;
$_SESSION['boat'] = $_SESSION['boat'] + 1;

header("Location: betalning.php");
?>
```

The first a tag add a car to the cart and the second a tag add a boat to the cart. How do i detect which one of the a tag that has been clicked, and if i now click on any of the a tags both a car and a boat will be added to the cart.

Comment: do you want the page to be notified or the serer?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/ is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add GET parameters to the links:

```
<a href="laggtill.php?add=car">Add car</a>
```

And then in your PHP document:

```
if($_GET['add'] == 'car'){
  $_SESSION['car'] += 1;
}
// etc...
```

This is basically the easiest way to pass data from one page to another using a link.

Answer (score -1):

The concept that you should use. is Ajax.

Every click and others things with the browser only happens on the client ( browser ).

1. Then when you do click. The browser has send request to server.
2. The server, get values that you send from browser and it proccess.

---

Some simple may be:

// Html

```
<a id="linkone" href="laggtill.php">+</a>
<a id="linktwo" href="laggtill.php">+</a>
```

//Javascript

```
// Use jquery
$("#linkone").on("click", function(){

    //function that send request to server
    $.post('someurl.php', {})
        .success(function(res){
            console.log(res);
            // If you stay here, the procces should be ended
        })
    // if you return false, the click dont redirect other window
    // if you return true, the click redirect other window
    return false;
});
```

// php file for first link

```
<?php
    //capture values
    // But only is a clic, then there is not values
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['car'] = $_SESSION['car'] + 1;
    // If you want some simple, one file only works for one link
    // For the other link, you should create other file same to this.
    header("Location: betalning.php"); // With ajax dont use this line, 

?>
```